# Make checkbox as a link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, checkbox

I want the `html.checkbox()` in ASP.NET MVC to be as a link that goes to an action controller (GET and not POST).

Question:
It is possible to make the `html.checkbox()` to act as a "actionlink" instead of going to the  FormCollection without using Javascript and JQuery or any additional plugin?

Comment: y on earth would you need that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wouldn't be possible in any framework as checkboxes are just static input elements. They have no ability to trigger any sort of action on their own, hence where javascript and event handlers comes in.

You could try making a form who's method is GET, but it would still have to go somewhere.. I guess you could make an action that handles various states of a checkbox and then routes to the correct page, however you'd still need to submit this form by having the user click a submit (again because the only way to trigger an action from clicking a checkbox is by using javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You could also fake a checkbox using css and checkbox-like images.

```
<a href="yourUrl" class="someClassThatIncludesYourCheckbox">text goes here</a>
```

If you need to show it as either checked or unchecked, you would use two classes with two different checkbox-like images.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible without javascript.
Except for buttons and links, no controls actually do anything but change their own value in the DOM.

It would however be rather trivial to add an onclick to your checkbox that would do whatever (including a GET request).